# Setting method as default method in geom_smooth gives different result

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some data and have the following code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = data) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 1/15, color = 'blue')+
  scale_y_continuous('y')+
  scale_x_continuous('x')+
  geom_smooth(stat = 'smooth', color = 'Red')
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

But if I specify 'gam' in the the `geom_smooth` function, like:

```
geom_smooth(stat = 'smooth', color = 'Red', method = 'gam')
```

I get a different result:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [Documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html), you can see that:

> smoothing method (function) to use, eg. "lm", "glm", "gam", "loess",
>   "rlm".
>
> For method = "auto" the smoothing method is chosen based on the size
>   of the largest group (across all panels). loess is used for less than
>   1,000 observations; otherwise gam is used with formula = y ~ s(x, bs =
>   "cs"). Somewhat anecdotally, loess gives a better appearance, but is
>   O(n^2) in memory, so does not work for larger datasets.

Note that when method 'auto' uses gam, it also changes the formula. The default formula is

> formula = y ~ x

So in the first scenario, it uses method gam, with the modified function function y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"). The second time, you only specify that method 'gam' should be used, but you don't overwrite the formula, so y ~x is still used. You could do this:

```
geom_smooth(stat = 'smooth', color = 'Red', method = 'gam', formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"))
```

To get the same result. Hope this helps!